# DomainUpDown control inside the GridView

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I want to add DomainUpDown control inside a DataGridView as a separate column. Each time a new row is added, I want that DomainUpDown control also be added. I also want to know when the user click the DomainUp or DomainDown button in DomainUpDown control for each row. Is it possible or not? I am using language vb.net/C#. I want to do this in winform not in ASP. Any help or suggestion please!!!

Comment: what have you written so far and if its for winform or asp.net?

Comment: Use DataGridView instead. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7tas5c80%28v=VS.90%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do/know is how to add an unbound column to an already data bound DataGridView, because from your description you are trying to add a column to a grid which already contains other data bound columns. In fact it would be easier if you had such column in the DataTable, also because with unbound columns you need to make a slightly bigger effort to populate and save the data from/to somewhere.

anyway it should be possible, MSDN explains it here: [How to: Add an Unbound Column to a Data-Bound Windows Forms DataGridView Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkatshfa.aspx)